# COUNTUNIQUEIFS malfunction on CRITERION_RANGE dates beginning with zero

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In [this given spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JZM6VX5dDJlJUwNGG91JFc34FEaiwhfWnWAw_xTbRPQ/edit#gid=602994572) COUNTUNIQUEIFS is returning wrong values whenever it counts unique strings between dates that have zero as its leading number.

The formula is `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:AL2<>""; COUNTUNIQUEIFS(Publications!C3:C; Publications!A3:A;"<="&DATEVALUE(B2:AL2&"/"&A2&"/"&A1); Publications!B3:B;">="&DATEVALUE(B2:AL2&"/"&A2&"/"&A1) );""))`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try this and drag to last column =COUNTUNIQUEIFS(Publications!$C$3:$C;Publications!$A$3:$A;Text($B$2:$AF$2&"/"&$A$2&"/"&$A$1;"YYYY-MM-DD"))

Comment: Can you visually clarify what's the desired output and what are you getting instead, as well as clarifying where is this formula located?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:2=IF(;;);;IFNA(HLOOKUP(B2:2; TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TEXT(
 FILTER(Days!A3:A; YEAR(Days!A3:A)=A1; MONTH(Days!A3:A)=MONTH(A2&1)); "dd");
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")); 2; 0); 0)))
```

[image]